# Adwords - "Google Site Stats - learn more" - where is this assigned?

Tags: google-ads-api

I am new to Adwords and have been tasked with removing

> Google Site Stats - learn more

from a web page. When I access the Adwords admin page I can't find a reference to the page so I can turn the notification off. Can someone please tell me how to find the page in the Adwords admin site so I can turn it off?

Thanks,
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off the Site Stats thing in AdWords via the Conversions area:

1. Log in to AdWords
2. Click on the "Tools" menu and select "Conversions"
3. Click on the Conversion entry you want to remove the site stats logo from.
4. Click on the "Settings" tab.
5. Click on the "Edit Settings" button
6. At the bottom of that is the "Tracking indicator" section where you can turn it off.
7. Save the changes.
8. Replace the existing code on your website with the new code from the "Code" tab.

(this is a long-winded way of saying that you can just change 'var google_conversion_format = "2"' to 'var google_conversion_format = "3"' in the actual conversion tag)

Note that it is recommended you update your site's privacy policy to let your users know about this tracking if you hide the tracking indicator.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks matt1, my problem is trying to match the conversion name to the web page in question that has a .aspx name. Is there a way to do that? Thanks again.

Comment: Each conversion has a unique google_conversion_id - if you find the ID from the page's source code, you can then go and look through the conversion tags one by one in AdWords to find the right one.  I am not aware of a quicker way of doing this, sorry.

Comment: Okay, I took your advice and changed google_conversion_format which I found on the .aspx page. That seems to be working. If so, I don't think I'll need to go thru the Adwords admin process. Would you agree? Thanks.

Comment: Yep - if you changed it in the AdWords UI, it would just be changing that value anyway so you've saved yourself the bother!